# How can I save a Foundry Scenario and use it in another Workshop module?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-scenarios, foundry-workshop

I've created a Scenario in Foundry Workshop, and wish to reuse it in another Workshop module. Is there a way to accomplish this task without needing to recreate the same Scenario multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you can create a button group to save a Scenario. You can specify a "save scenario" action along with separate Create and Update actions. See the relevant product documentation at https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/scenarios-save/#saving-scenarios-as-a-user

Saved scenarios are not intrinsically tied to the Workshop module in which they were created, and can be loaded in any other module. See the relevant product documentation at https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/scenarios-load/